# What manga/webtoon was the author referring to in his notes on chapter 113 of The Gamer?

Tags: the-gamer

In the author's notes in [chapter 113](http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=552960&no=114) of *The Gamer*, he is talking about a webtoon that is apparently very similar, and I assume a lot of people have asked them if they got anything to do with it, which they deny.

[image].[image]

<sup>The original panel and its unofficial English translation. Click to see in full size.</sup>

Can anyone tell me what webtoon they mean?

Comment: It is probably a webtoon, that started pretty recently and hence isn't being translated.

Answer (score -3):

They could be taking about DICE not 100% sure though.

DICE = What if you can restart your life with a different setting just like a game? DONG TAE always get bullied by his classmates, but TAE BIN, sits right next to him, is handsome and popular at school; and now, TAE BIN suggests DONG TAE to play a little game.

Thanks,
Pyrotek

Comment: Could you add proofs of your statements? :)

Comment: Considering Dice has been around for quite a while, I can't imagine the author and artist suddenly worrying about it now. It's very likely a webtoon that doesn't have an active translation project anyways.

Answer (score -3):

Possibly *Dusk Howler*, it's a gamer webtoon and there is only 24 chapters. It's about a young man who had a great scores in school but have 0 social IQ so he joins a game where his conscious is uploaded so like the gamer the Mc get to level up , learn skills and it's a gaming world . and it's a new Webtoon. Connecting the dots together it makes sense.

Comment: Could you expand on why you think dust howler is the answer to the OP's question?

Comment: it's about a young man who had a great scores in school but have 0 social IQ  so he joins a game where his conscious is uploaded  so like the gamer the Mc get to level up , learn skills  and it's a gaming world . and it's a new Webtoon  .connecting the dots together it makes sense .